# Send iMessage to use madrid,CKMadridEntity kept returning nil

Tags: ios, iphone, imessage

//I was adapting this SMS code to use madrid

```
CKSMSService *smsService = [CKSMSService sharedSMSService];
CKConversationList *conversationList = nil;
conversationList = [CKConversationList sharedConversationList];
CKSMSEntity *ckEntity = [smsService copyEntityForAddressString:@\"555-555-5555\"];
CKConversation *conversation = [conversationList conversationForRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ckEntity] create:TRUE service:smsService];
NSString *groupID = [conversation groupID];
CKSMSMessage *ckMsg = [smsService _newSMSMessageWithText:msg forConversation:conversation];
[smsService sendMessage:ckMsg];
[ckMsg release]; 

//but CKMadridEntity kept returning nil (psuedo code)

CKMadridService *madridService = [CKMadridService sharedMadridService];
CKConversationList *conversationList = nil;
conversationList = [CKConversationList sharedConversationList];
CKMadridEntity *ckEntity = [madridService copyEntityForAddressString:@\"555-555-5555\"]; //tried @\"whoever@gmail.com\" too


**I am using xcode5.1, private api for ios5.1.
```

i want to use private api send sms with imessage ,the private api in the chatkit.framework code pasted.
    so, what should I do?  please help me!!**